# Python - sort a list of nested lists

Tags: python, list, sorting, nested-lists

I have input consisting of a list of nested lists like this:

```
l = [[[[[39]]]], [1, 2, 3], [4, [5, 3], 1], [[[[8, 9], 10], 11], 12]]
```

I want to sort this list based on the sum of all the numbers in the nested lists... so, the values I want to sort by of l would look like this:

```
[39, 6, 13, 50]
```

Then I want to sort based on these. So the output should be:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, [5, 3], 1], [[[[39]]]], [[[[8, 9], 10], 11], 12]]
```

What's a nice pythonic way of doing this?

Comment: Break the problem down into steps. Do you know how to sort "based on" that result? Do you know how to get that result for a given element?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A slight simplification and generalization to the answers provided so far, using a recent addition to python's syntax:

```
>>> l = [[[[[39]]]], [1, 2, 3], [4, [5, 3], 1], [[[[8, 9], 10], 11], 12]]
>>> def asum(t): return sum(map(asum, t)) if hasattr(t, '__iter__') else t
...
>>> sorted(l, key=asum)
[[1, 2, 3], [4, [5, 3], 1], [[[[39]]]], [[[[8, 9], 10], 11], 12]]
```

Answer (score 12):

A little recursive function would do it:

```
def asum(a):
    if isinstance(a, list):
        return sum(asum(x) for x in a)
    else:
        return a

l = [[[[[39]]]], [1, 2, 3], [4, [5, 3], 1], [[[[8, 9], 10], 11], 12]]
l.sort(key=asum)
print l
```

Comment: I'd say that `hasattr` is a more general solution in this case than `isinstance`.

Answer (score 5):

```
l.sort(key=sum_nested)
```

Where `sum_nested()` is:

```
def sum_nested(astruct):
    try: return sum(map(sum_nested, astruct))
    except TypeError:
        return astruct


assert sum_nested([[([8, 9], 10), 11], 12]) == 50
```