# Sorting lists based on a particular element - Python

Tags: python, list, sorting

How do I sort a list of lists based on the first element of the lists in Python?

```
>>> list01 = (['a','b','c'],['b','a','d'],['d','e','c'],['a','f','d'])
>>> map(sorted, list01)
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'd'], ['c', 'd', 'e'], ['a', 'd', 'f']]
>>> sorted(map(sorted, list01))
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'd'], ['a', 'd', 'f'], ['c', 'd', 'e']]
```

Comment: This looks like it might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/q/280222/2740086

Comment: By default, the sort method sorts in order of index, starting at zero or the first element.

Comment: If you sort only on the first element, then something like `[['a','z','z'],['a','a',b']]` will sort to itself (because Python's sort is stable.)  Is that what you want?

Answer (score 1):

Python's sorted() can receive a function to sort by.
If you want to sort by the first element in each sublist, you can use the following:

```
>>> lst = [[2, 3], [1, 2]]
>>> sorted(lst, key=lambda x: x[0])
[[1, 2], [2, 3]]
```

For more information on sorted(), please see the [official docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted).

Answer (score 1):

```
from operator import itemgetter    
sorted(list01, key=itemgetter(0))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> sorted(list01, key=lambda l: l[0])
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'f', 'd'], ['b', 'a', 'd'], ['d', 'e', 'c']]
```

Is this what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the passing a `key` function to the `sorted` (as show in earlier answers) you can also pass it a `cmp` (comparison) function in Python2 as follows:

```
sorted(list01, cmp=lambda b, a: cmp(b[0], a[0]))
```

Output of above expression would be same as that of using the the `key` function.

Although they have removed the `cmp` argument in Python3 from `sorted`, https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#sorted, and using a `key` function is the only choice.